# Error USB3 UAS passthrough VMWare Workstation 15

Tags: hard-drive, usb, virtualbox, external-hard-drive, vmware

**Specs:**

- i7 5700 HQ
- 3x USB3 ports
- Windows 10 1809

**Tested not working:**

- Seagate 1TB USB3 HDD
- Seagate 4TB USB3 HDD

**Tested working:**

- Philips 32GB USB3 Flash Drive

**Issue:**

All of the devices work flawlessly under my host. They also used to work under VMWare, until one morning they simply didn't. The problem seems to be in UAS (USB-attached-SCSI), since mass storage mode works (check edit on bottom).

When I connect the Seagate HDDs to a Windows guest (VMWare tools installed), the USB device would start going on and off very rapidly, until it stops with this error in `Device Manager > USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)`:

```
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)
The USB hub failed to reset.
```

When connected to a Ubuntu 18 guest (VMWare tools installed), in USB3 compatibility mode set from virtual box settings, I get the following `dmesg`:

```
[  316.658762] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  316.681561] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=231a, bcdDevice= 7.08
[  316.681563] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  316.681564] usb 4-1: Product: Expansion
[  316.681565] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  316.681566] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: NAA340A2
[  316.694030] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  316.699310] scsi host33: uas
[  316.701526] usb 4-1: stat urb: status -32
[  316.701552] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 data cmplt err -32 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[  316.701555] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Inquiry 12 00 00 00 24 00
[  316.701636] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
```

For comparison, the Philips Flash Drive (working):

```
[  472.401145] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  472.436450] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5500, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  472.436452] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  472.436453] usb 4-2: Product: USB Flash Drive
[  472.436460] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Philips
[  472.436461] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 070851EF951C7401
[  472.437919] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  472.438011] scsi host33: usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[  473.452528] scsi 33:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Philips  USB Flash Drive  PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
```

**EDIT:**
Found a working workaround in Workstaton 12 [release notes](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/12.0/rn/workstation-12-release-notes.html#knownissues):

> A UAS device connected to a USB 3.0 port on a Windows 7 or later host
>   might fail to successfully connect to the guest
>   ...
>   NOTE: This procedure makes the device function as a USB 3.0 mass storage device and not as a UAS device, which might result in a slight
>   degradation in performance while reading and writing to the device.

However, doing this involves a performance penalty. The issue is also no longer listed under Workstation 14/15 release notes so it should have been fixed, but it is not.

**EDIT2:**
A similar problem has been reported by somebody else on the VMWare Community Forum [here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/611564).

Comment: Have you tried to use a different cable?  Are you sure these devices are operational?

Comment: Yes, they are two separate cables and everything works flawlessly under my Windows host. I will update the post with this information.